# Could not find method mavenCentral()

Tags: android, gradle

I think I miss something about  `mavenCentral()`
thanks a lot

that's error message :

**Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method mavenCentral() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.**

I also add to `buildscript`

```
 maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
```

but same error again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place it in `repositories` block, not `dependencies`:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()  //here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mavenCentral()` is a repo (the [central Maven repository](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)), not a dependency.

**Move** the [`mavenCentral()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:maven_central) in the `buildscript/repositories` block.

```
buildscript{
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()  
  }
  ...
}
```